# ffmpeg - splitting a .mov fails for me

Tags: ffmpeg

i'm using python code that takes in a movie file and successfully splits it into smaller files. However, i've hit a deadend regarding ffmpeg:

I simply can't convert anything EXCEPT avi and mpg files. My goal is to convert .mov files at well.

The command line for my MOV file is:

```
ffmpeg -i testMOV2.mov -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:30 success.mov
```

Error message is

```
[mpeg4 @ 0xa1f1de0] Invalid pixel aspect ratio 10000/10000, limit is 255/255
Output #0, mov, to 'success.mov':
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 960x600 [PAR 10000:10000 DAR 8:5], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 15 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-10-19 18:44:30
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: libfaac, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-10-19 18:44:30
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

According to the error message, what can i do about the bit_rate, width, height, aspect ratio, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, i managed to fix it. Don't know the exact problem, but i uninstalled ffmpeg on my linux machine and did it all over again.

specifically, i followed these instructions:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9868359&postcount=1289